# Getting Twitch followers using Twitch API in PHP

Tags: php, twitch

What I'm trying to do is make a twitch follower alert in PHP. The only stuff so far that I have gotten done is find out where to get the info from. I need assistance decoding the info, and then getting the user name and setting it to a string. The place for the recent followers is: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trippednw/follows/?limit=1

Comment: The info is formatted as JSON. You should use a JSON decoder to parse it, and then you can access the user.name property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data Twitch's API gives you is in JSON format (JavaScript Object Notation). You can decode it using `json_decode($data, true)`. This gives you an associative array with the required fields. For example, to get the name of the user who most recently followed:

```
json_decode($twitch_data, true)['follows'][0]['user']['name']
```

**Update:**

Here's a more detailed answer. First, you're going to have to get the data from the Twitch API via a get request using `file_get_contents()`. Then, you parse the resulting JSON using the method described above and `echo` that out onto the page. Here's the full code:

```
<?php
$api_url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trippednw/follows/?limit=1';
$api_data = file_get_contents($api_url);
$last_follow = json_decode($api_data, true)['follows'][0]['user']['name'];
echo "The last user to follow <strong>trippednw</strong> on Twitch is <strong>" . $last_follow . "</strong>.";
?>
```

Comment: How can I send the JSON decoding to a string and then print the string?

Comment: @InnecticGaming I've updated the answer. Hopefully this clears things up.